# how to scroll only a particular area of the page instead of complete page using selenium/selenide

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenide

I have a web page which contains different frames e.g left frame, top frame and middle frame. The middle frame contains a list of files which can be scrolled. 
I want to scroll that frame page by page till end. How can I do it in selenium or selenide?

Following JS code i have already tried.

```
 jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

Comment: Yes it it correct, what is the issue

Comment: Please share URL and HTML